# SQL to update a Select Statement column based on another Columns value but only if condition is met

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, case

I have a select statement and would like to update `Task_Days_Due` to a string (`N/A - Task is Closed`) if column `task_status2` value is `Closed` Currently it shows the number of days until due but this is irrelevant if clised.

[image]

Here is the current select:

```
SELECT

    Report_Run_Date,
    incident_number,
    INC_Reported_Date,
    TASK_id,
    TASK_Assigneee, 
    TASK_Status, -- Staged 1000, Assigned 2000, Pending 3000, Work In Progress 4000, Waiting 5000, Closed 6000, ByPassed 7000
    Task_Status2,
    -- Set RAG column to RAG is not closed
    case    WHEN TASK_Status = 6000  THEN "N/A - Task is Closed"
            WHEN Task_Days_Due <= 0  THEN 'Red'
            WHEN Task_Days_Due > 0 and Task_Days_Due <= 7 THEN 'Amber'
            WHEN Task_Days_Due > 7 THEN 'Green'
            WHEN Task_Days_Due is NULL THEN 'No Task End Date'
    end     as Red_Amber_Green,
    Task_Days_Due, ?????
```

My challenge is I want to leave the value as is if the condition is not met. previous attempts are overwriting the value to null if column `task_status2` value was not `Closed`

Comment: which DB are you using? You can do this in for example Oracle like "decode(task_status2, 'Closed', 'N/A - Task is Closed', task_days_due) as task_days_due"

Comment: Impala, which is very similar to SQL Server etc

Comment: you can use decode in impala as I see, soo try what I wrote before...

Comment: Ok will check when back in office 

Comment: AnalysisException: Incompatible return types 'STRING' and 'INT' of exprs ''N/A - Task is Closed'' and 'task_days_due'. task_days_due is int....Need to conert task_status2 to char before decode?

Comment: I don't use impala but it seems you have to cast task_days_due  into string if you want this. Try "decode(task_status2, 'Closed', 'N/A - Task is Closed', cast(task_days_due as STRING)) as task_days_due"

Comment: @OracleDev awsome! Working. Want to post solution and I'll tick?

Comment: Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT

    Report_Run_Date,
    incident_number,
    INC_Reported_Date,
    TASK_id,
    TASK_Assigneee, 
    TASK_Status, -- Staged 1000, Assigned 2000, Pending 3000, Work In Progress 4000, Waiting 5000, Closed 6000, ByPassed 7000
    Task_Status2,
    -- Set RAG column to RAG is not closed
    case    WHEN TASK_Status = 6000  THEN "N/A - Task is Closed"
            WHEN Task_Days_Due <= 0  THEN 'Red'
            WHEN Task_Days_Due > 0 and Task_Days_Due <= 7 THEN 'Amber'
            WHEN Task_Days_Due > 7 THEN 'Green'
            WHEN Task_Days_Due is NULL THEN 'No Task End Date'
    end     as Red_Amber_Green,
    decode(task_status2, 'Closed', 'N/A - Task is Closed', cast(task_days_due as STRING)) as task_days_due
```